# How to change preloaded php version to MAMP in Mac/OSX

Tags: php, macos, git-bash

I am using Mac/OSX for the first time and I have installed `MAMP` and set PHP Standard Version as `7.1.6` but when I have run `php -v` command in the terminal I am getting below details:

```
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Feb  7 2017 16:18:37) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Can you please guide how to use 7.1.6 version instead of 5.6.30.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try googling it?  First hit I get is a full fledged tutorial. https://developerjack.com/blog/2015/installing-php7-with-homebrew/

Answer (score 6):

### Instructions to Change PHP Installation

First, Lets find out what version of PHP we're running (To find out if it's the default version).

To do that, Within the terminal, Fire this command:

```
which php
```

This should output the path to the default PHP install which comes preinstalled by Mac OS X, by default it has to be (Assuming you've not changed it before):

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Now, We just need to swap this over to the PHP that is installed with MAMP, which is located at /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.6/bin

To do this, We need to edit the .bash_profile and add the MAMP version of PHP to the PATH variable.

Follow these simple steps:

Within the Terminal, run

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Type i and then paste the following at the top of the file:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.6/bin:$PATH
```

Hit ESC, Type :wq, and hit Enter

In Terminal, run source ~/.bash_profile

In Terminal, type in which php again and look for the updated string. If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.

Comment: While this solution works fine I wonder if it's possible to get the active PHP version MAMP is using (when running MAMP) inside .bash_profile? I have to switch between PHP version here and there and would like to match that dynamically. I found a way to get the latest version using: `PHP_VERSION="command ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1"` but not the active